# Why piping into node not showing output when there is no console.log?

Tags: linux, bash, node.js

This is the Linux bash terminal:

```
$ node 
> 'aBc'.toLowerCase()
'abc'
> .exit
$ echo "console.log('aBc'.toLowerCase()) " | node
abc
$ echo "'aBc'.toLowerCase()" | node
```

You can see when I type in Node REPL `'aBc'.toLowerCase()` I get the output. But when I execute `echo "'aBc'.toLowerCase()" | node` I don't get any output. Why?

There is a way to get the output without `console.log`? Maybe is it goes to other ouptput stream?

Answer (score 0):

Found an solution on Reddit by `sn-x` user `09f911029d7` users.

node no showing normal statments output when non running in interactive mode. To see the output there are 2 options:

```
node -i "5+5"
```

This will force node to run as in interactive mode, and will show the output.

The other way is to use:

```
node -p "5+5"
```

This will tell node to print the executed last value of the statment. (same result as before).